# Are you able to import 2 of the same image sequence files and start them at different frames?

Tags: image

I have imported certain png sequence files as planes for effects. I would like to use the same file in the same scene twice but when I edit any change it is applied to both objects. I imported them both unchecking the option for "overwrite material" but that is not working. I'm using Blender 2.83.

Comment: I'd say you'd have to give each plane a different Material slot. Then texture that slot with the same texture file. If it's a video you can offset it's starting (scene) frame in the new material slot so it starts later than the 1st.  That's done in the texture properties for that slot.

Answer (score 2):

This is me answering my own question months later in case others have the same issue.
So according to "Lateasusual":
"[image]image sequences can only load one image at a time - here even though the image is used in 2 places with different frames, the same frame will be shown for both of them

- so all you need to do is just click the 2 button
  "
  ---- Lateasusual